# (Sandbox solution) Ensure my javascript file is loaded after core.js

Tags: javascript, sandbox-solution, custom-actions, core-js

Using a CustomAction in the location of a scriptlink, I'm inserting a javascript code, however I need this code to run after core.js runs. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

My CustomAction elements file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Location="ScriptLink" Sequence="10000"  ScriptBlock="
                var domain = document.domain;
                /* 
                   rest of my Javascript Code */
};"/>
  </Elements>
```

I have tried to put my code within a function, and call ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded but that didn't seem to work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Location="ScriptLink" Sequence="10000"  ScriptBlock="
                ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MyCode, 'core.js');

                function MyCode(){ 
                      var domain = document.domain;

                   /*rest of my Javascript Code */
    };"/>
      </Elements>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The way you are using it should work. Can you see the script on the page? Are you getting any JS errors on the page?

Comment: I'm getting no JS errors, and the script is loading according to IE developer toolbar. The JS is written by a 3rd party, and they told us it needs to be run after core.js, so perhaps there is actually a problem with their code, we have already found a few mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look in here Paul, this might help you out.

http://ensure.codeplex.com/

Also Waldek provides an extensive overview of the problem in his blogpost, 
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/dynamically-loading-javascript-sandbox/ , which suggest some ways to get around the sandbox' limitations with regards to loading scripts.

Comment: This is a very good answer. It didn't solve my problem as I now think the problem is with the js code, not with order I run it in. I've marked it as correct answer as it did confirm, and also offer me different ways to run js code in different order, which will be very helpful in SP2013.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered but something not mentioned

I used the script block method to output the  tags like this

```
ScriptBlock="document.write('&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;~site/JavascriptReferenceTestAssets/Test.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/' + 'script&gt;');"
```

Which will put it at the top.  But to ensure it loads after everything else, use the defer option on the script tag.

**References**

http://blog.voyta.net/2010/09/12/referencing-javascript-files-using-customaction-in-sharepoint-2010-sandboxed-solutions/

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp